# What is Costa Rica's extradition policy for EU citizens?

Tags: extradition, costa-rica

Several Romanian public figures (politicians, prosecutors etc.) that have serious legal issues have chosen Costa Rica as a safe place shortly before the final terms in their trials.

Two examples are shown [in this article](http://www.romaniajournal.ro/elena-udrea-confirms-she-is-in-costa-rica-pregnant-with-twins/):

> Elena Udrea, former Development and Tourism Minister in the Emil Boc
>   cabinet, is prosecuted in several files, and is reportedly in Costa
>   Rica, living in the same neighbourhood with the former National
>   Directorate for Combating Organised Crime and Terrorism (DIICOT) head,
>   Alina Bica, also prosecuted, who arrived there last month.

Some journalists argued that Costa Rica was chosen due to harder to obtain extradition in case of them being convicted. However, I could not find references to back up these claims.

**Question:** What is Costa Rica's extradition policy for EU citizens?

Comment: This may be a "Law" question rather than a politics question. But I'll note that extradition treaties are normally negotiated on a bilateral basis, not by the EU. So Romanian membership of the EU is not relevant.

Comment: @JamesK - I am not interested in the exact law details, but rather in an overview picture of extraditions Costa Rica -> EU countries. I am sure there is a reason why some Romanian crooks decided to go there when they are about to be convicted.